# Defining object

Tags: c++, library, compile, class

I am trying to hide libraries behind another, for simplicity. But I can't deal with the objects required by the libraries. Basically I want to use the objects both in my .cpp and .ino file, but I am getting errors about double definition, or not declared in this scope.

*test.ino*

```
#include "lib.h"
#include "obj.cpp"

void setup() {
  mesh.setNodeID(40);
  mesh.begin();
}

void loop() {
  mesh.update();
}
```

*lib.cpp*

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "lib.h"

#include "obj.cpp"

int message = 1;

void send() {

  if (!mesh.write(&message, 'C', sizeof(message))) {

    // If a write fails, check connectivity to the mesh network
    if ( ! mesh.checkConnection() ) {
      //refresh the network address
      Serial.println("Renewing Address");
      mesh.renewAddress();
    } else {
      Serial.println("Sending failed, Test OK");
    }
  } else {
    Serial.print("Sent OK");
  }
}
```

lib.h

```
#ifndef lib_h
#define lib_h

void send();

#endif
```

obj.cpp

```
#include "RF24.h"
#include "RF24Network.h"
#include "RF24Mesh.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8);
RF24Network network(radio);
RF24Mesh mesh(radio, network);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```C++
#include "obj.cpp"
```

Don't include .cpp files. That gets them compiled twice (or more) and then you get duplicate definitions. Include .h files only.

What you are calling obj.cpp should probably be obj.h, however I haven't actually tried to compile it.

---

> it says that I have multiple definitions of the three objects

I tried compiling but I don't have the RF24 library. Anyway, this is wrong:

**obj.h**

```C++
#include "RF24.h"
#include "RF24Network.h"
#include "RF24Mesh.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

RF24 radio(7, 8);
RF24Network network(radio);
RF24Mesh mesh(radio, network);
```

You can't *define* things there (like `radio`) which get included in multiple files. `obj.h` or `obj.cpp` it will be the same thing.

These lines need to be in **one** .cpp file:

```C++
RF24 radio(7, 8);
RF24Network network(radio);
RF24Mesh mesh(radio, network);
```

Thus you cannot include that file in another file. However you can refer to them by making them `extern` in a header file, eg.

```C++
extern RF24 radio;
extern RF24Network network;
extern RF24Mesh mesh;
```

Comment: I changed obj.cpp to obj.h but it says that I have multiple definitions of the three objects: sketch\test.ino.cpp.o:(.bss.mesh+0x0): multiple definition of `mesh'
sketch\lib.cpp.o:(.bss.mesh+0x0): first defined here
sketch\test.ino.cpp.o: In function `setup':
D:\\test/test.ino:4: multiple definition of `radio'
sketch\lib.cpp.o:(.bss.radio+0x0): first defined here
sketch\test.ino.cpp.o: In function `setup':
D:\\test/test.ino:4: multiple definition of `network'
sketch\lib.cpp.o:(.bss.network+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1